# default timeout for cron in ubuntu

Tags: php, ubuntu, amazon-ec2, cron, exec

I have PHP script that does almost 4 hours task, normally the Online services for Cron runs your script for `300sec` or limited time so I thought I should run my cron on EC2 instance, 
My question is ,

1. is there any default timeout for my cron, if my cron runs it will run upto completion of script?
2. Is there any library or too for setting up cron rather than going through putty/SSH?

I got mixed answers on Google,therefore I am asking,

Comment: If you have cpanel on your server, there  is a cpanel API which allows you to edit the cron jobs.

Comment: @Adelphia EC2 servers has no cPanel, other than the aws dashboard :)

Comment: The script is on your server?

Comment: How do you call it right now?

Comment: @michael I create a cron job in shell

Comment: yes, but with which command? :)

Comment: @michael crontab ofcourse

Comment: a command is, f.e. php runscript.php. crontab is simply a list where you put all your commands in that should be executed